What old 50's or 60's Sci Fi movie is this scene from?
I remember watching an old Sci Fi movie scene where some guy is stumbling down a staircase going around one of those big spherical gas storage tanks (like at a refinery).  His hand was on the tank as he went down, leaving a dark streak on the tank. 
I know it's ancient and obscure, but from time to time it flashes in my head and I'd like to know what it was from. Any Sci Fi buffs of that era know what it might be? 
UPDATE: In response to the comments, here is more detail:
It was, as I recall, black and white.
I'm almost certain it was a movie, but I was only 7 or 8 when I saw it, so I can't be 100% on that.

Please put as much detail as possible.  Are you sure its a movie - like was it ~90 minutes or more long, or an episode of something like the Twilight Zone.  Was it in black and white, or color.

I also recall seeing a movie like this. The image in my head is one where the oil in the tanks came to life and created havoc and destruction on the local community.

A sci-fi movie from the fifties with spherical tanks? If it was British, you may be thinking of the BBC miniseries Quatermass II or the Hammer film based thereon, Quatermass 2 (known as "Enemy from Space" in the US).
Was the scene anything like this?

Or, from earlier in the sequence:


No, don't think so.  As I picture it, the shot was from further away, and the guy was near the top of the tank.  Plus, the staircaise was winding around the tank.

I think the stairway curves around above this shot. Also, it could have been from the other version (I think this shot is from the miniseries and you may have seen the film). I'll see if I can find another view.

I've added a shot from this fan-made trailer (@t = 1m 49s) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a6iN4g0hSI.

Thanks much James.  I suppose it's possible that this is what I'm remembering, although I didn't see the scene that I have in my mind.  I think I'll have to watch the entire movie.  At least I have something to look for!

It's worth watching even if it isn't the one you were thinking of!

I think that The Hideous Sun Demon (1959) ended with a man who turned into a monster atop a big storage tank so it might be the movie you remember.

Another movie involving a man walking down a large tank's spiral stair case, may have been the miniseries, The Stand by Stephen King?
The guy's an insane guy who keeps yelling "My life for him!"
The guy ends up blowing up the stored petroleum in the refinery tank.
He then tows a nuclear missile into the town where Satan is, and his skin is badly burned from exposure to the radiation.
I hope that helps.

The Stand mini-series is from the 1990s. Way out of OP's time frame.
